# Custom json pagser in Jersey 2

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

I got application with Jersey 2 rest services. From UI I pass json and on server side I got DTO objects. Everything works fine, json is being parsed automatically into dto objects. Now I need to extend this parsing (I want to user hibernate validation). Which class should I extend? Some examples?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle Resource validation in REST webservices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218159/how-to-handle-resource-validation-in-rest-webservices)

Comment: See also https://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhaktimehta/archive/2013/10/30/jax-rs-and-bean-validation